# Web page text display problem

Tags: php, css, text-formatting

I keep getting these weird text characters when I display user submitted text. like in the following example below. Is there a way I can fox this using PHP, CSS or something so that the characters are displayed properly?

Here is the problem text.

```
Problems of â��real fontsâ�� on the web. The one line summary: 
different browsers and different platforms do â��hintingâ��
```

Here is my meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: What <meta> do you send? You should specify the content type in there, that would probably fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an encoding problem. Make sure you send the correct encoding to the browser. If it's UTF-8, you'll do it like this:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Also, make sure that you store the content using the same encoding throughout the entire system. Set your database tables to `utf8`. If you're using MySQL, run the `SET NAMES utf8` query when connecting to make sure you're running in UTF-8.

These weird characters occur when you suddenly switch encoding.

Also, some functions in PHP take a `$charset` parameter (e.g. [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities)). Make sure you pass the correct charset to that one as well.

To make sure that PHP handles your charset correctly in all cases, you can set the [`default_charset`](http://php.net/default_charset) to `utf-8` (either in `php.ini` or using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set)).

Comment: but I already use the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @text: That's not necessarily enough. If your web server sends a proper header, then that will take precedence over your `<meta>` tag. PHP is configured to send it with `iso-8859-1` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Set your page to UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the char-set in header section.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
use this below one:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

or try this one:

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be problem with file encoding please check that your files is correctly encoded, saved as "UTF-8 without boom", also if you are saving to database use SET NAMES UTF-8